# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: ECDH for provider BC

Tags: java, android, bouncycastle

I have this exception in Android although I have downloaded the unlimited JCE Policy and I have added the lib bcprov. Also I have added the line:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

Please help me in knowing what is missing. I read other posts and found that they have done the above. The app crashes at loadprivatekey, in the line:

```
ECParameterSpec params = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec(CurveName);)
```

which is called from the `doECDH` function

```
   public static PrivateKey loadPrivateKey (byte [] data) throws Exception
  {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
     ECParameterSpec params = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec(CurveName);
    ECPrivateKeySpec prvkey = new ECPrivateKeySpec(new BigInteger(data), 
     params);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH", "BC");
    return kf.generatePrivate(prvkey);
}

public static String doECDH ( String data_Prv, String data_Pub) throws Exception
{
    byte[] dataPrv = hexToBytes(data_Prv);
    byte[] dataPub = hexToBytes(data_Pub);
    KeyAgreement ka = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH", "BC");
    ka.init(loadPrivateKey(dataPrv));
    ka.doPhase(loadPublicKey(dataPub), true);
    byte [] secret = ka.generateSecret();
    Shared_Key = bytesToHex(secret);
    //SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(secret, 0, secret.length, "ECDH");
    return Shared_Key;
}
```

Comment: Show code where you initialize ECDH

Comment: What's your BouncyCastle version? And which libs are you using (bcprov, bcmail, etc)?

Comment: bcprov-jdk15on-157

Comment: same code works perfectly from Eclipse!

Comment: If it works in eclipse, where does it not work? Might be using a different jre (meaning a different security policy file)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use spongycastle, add this to your build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.54.0.0'
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.54.0.0'
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:1.54.0.0'
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pg:1.54.0.0'
```

Add this code:

```
static {
    Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
}
```

And use this:

```
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH", "SC");
```

and this:

```
KeyAgreement ka = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH", "SC");
```